# need to create regular expression for dynamic words from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsregularexpression, nsmutableattributedstring

I want to make regular expression for the dynamic words which comes from array and detect those word in array of string to make them linkable .

Eg. nsarray *arrOfStrings =@[@"This is sample string for objective c",@"Objective c or swift",@"Test string",@"iOS development",@"Re
gular expression link"];

```
nsarray *arrLinkWord =@[@"is",@"sample",@"or",@"link",@"Test"];
```

As well as in arabic also

Thank you

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, where you got stuck etc. You appear to be asking someone to write you an "a OR b OR c ..." regular expression, and OR is one of the core regular expression operators. Maybe you misunderstand how it works, or the issue is something else entirely - but without your attempt nobody can know. Edit your question to  include the additional info and someone will undoubtedly help you.

Comment: What is your question? What's the expected result?

Comment: I need display list of String in table view .In which i have to show some word clickable link like Wikipedia.I have used FRHyperLabel github in my project.Its working fine for english but when i convert to arabic it doesnot clickable.Thats my issue